# Need to incorporate some features from Excel. Is that possible?

Tags: excel, user-interface, wizard

I know one of the main principles of Software Engineering is DRY(Don't Repeat Yourself), that's why I don't want write another implementation of something I already know exists in Excel.

I was wondering if it is possible to take a feature from an existing program, and use it?

The feature I'm particularly interested in is in the Data section in Excel, there is ability to import a text with data.  It opens a wizard that makes the user describe his datafile, and then Excel tries it's best to import it into Excel.

What I want to do is to make another version of this data text importer, except with more specific options. Would I have to make another instance of Excel's importer?

Comment: If your end-user had Excel installed then maybe you could automate some of that process using Excel's functionality, but you can't easily add new features to the built-in workflow.  If you want more specific functionality, then likely you'll have to recreate the wizard yourself.

Comment: Thanks, a good straightforward answer is what I was looking for.